# $f:S \to S^*$ is continuous $\iff$ $f^{-1} (B(x^*,r))$ is open ball

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ and $(S^*,d^*)$ be metric spaces. Consider $f:S\to S^*$. Show that

$f$ is continuous $\iff$ for every open ball $B(x^*,r)$ in $S^*$ (where $x^*\in S^*$, $r>0$), we have $f^{-1} (B(x^*,r))$ is open in $S$.

My attempt:

$\Rightarrow$ If $f$ is continuous, then the preimage of any open set is open. Since any open ball is an open set, it follows that $f^{-1} (B(x^*,r))$ is open in $S$.

This direction is easy, but I am not sure about the other one:

$\Leftarrow $ Suppose that for every open ball $B(x^*,r)$ in $S^*$ (where $x^*\in S^*$, $r>0$), we have $f^{-1} (B(x^*,r))$ is open in $S$. Let $x\in S$, we want to show that $f$ is continuous at $x$. By the definition of continuity, given $\epsilon >0$, we want to show

$\exists \delta >0, \ \forall x' \in B(x,\delta)$ then $f(x')\in B(x^*=f(x),\epsilon)$.

Since $f^{-1} (B(x^*,\epsilon))$ is open and $x \in f^{-1} (B(x^*,\epsilon))$,

$\implies \exists \delta >0, \ B(x,\delta) \subset f^{-1} (B(x^*,\epsilon))$

$\implies f(x')\in B(x^*,\epsilon)$

Is my answer correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Your proof is correct.

Comment: You can avoid $\epsilon/\delta$ stuff by saying that any open set is a union of open balls. (BTW, the title is incorrect).

Comment: @BernardPan Thank you!

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you!